# Getting historical data for all companies listed in a stock exchange (Hong Kong in my case)

Tags: database, finance, quantitative-finance, stocks, historical-db

I’m straggling to download historical data for my masters thesis. I need daily prices (only one per day e.g. adjusted close) of all companies listed in a stock exchange, specifically in Hong Kong SE, over 20 years including delisted and new starting with issuing day. Is there a way to do it with R? I am thinking about getting a list of all companies listed at every day over the past 20 years and then getting prices for that particular day and company. But I’m not sure who to put it into a code. Or maybe there is another way to do it? Perhaps with Bloomberg terminal? I got one at campus. I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: This should be closed because it is unclear, too broad and most of all off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

If i well understand your question. You need to work on R and manage a database of the HonKong SE stocks. For this task, I can advise you to go to [quandl](http://quandl.com).com. You can access it for free and  loading stock prices in R. You just have to sign into the api and get you Key. [direct link to Hong Kong page on quandl.com](https://www.quandl.com/data/HKEX-Hong-Kong-Exchange/usage/quickstart/r)